# How to cast lambda in Vala

Tags: lambda, delegates, vala

Keep receiving compile-time warring from `cc` (not `valac`). Tried to cast the lambda, but don't know how to. I'm new to Vala. Hope someone can help. Thanks a lot. The following code is an example where `cc` will complain about the incorrect type of the lambda, the argument of the method `foreach`. The Vala I'm using is version 0.36.1 and `cc` is version 4.9.2.

```
public static int main(string[] args)
{
    var hash = new GLib.HashTable<string, string>(GLib.str_hash, GLib.str_equal);
    hash.insert("one", "apple");
    hash.insert("two", "banana");
    hash.insert("three", "cherry");
    hash.foreach((key, val)=>stdout.printf("%s => %s\n", key, val));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can safely ignore warnings from your C compiler as long as

1. You are not writing VAPI bindings yourself. You should then make sure there are as few C warnings as possible.
2. They are not errors, but then you would not be able to create a binary anyway.

I usually pass "-X -w" to the vala compiler to suppress C warnings.

Let us look at your concrete example anyway, I get this warning (GCC 6.3.0 on MSYS2 64-Bit Windows):

```
d:/msys64/home/Admin/hash-test.vala.c: In function '_vala_main':
d:/msys64/home/Admin/hash-test.vala.c:69:30: warning: passing argument 2 of 'g_hash_table_foreach' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  g_hash_table_foreach (hash, ___lambda4__gh_func, NULL);
                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from D:/msys64/mingw64/include/glib-2.0/glib.h:50:0,
                 from d:/msys64/home/Admin/hash-test.vala.c:5:
D:/msys64/mingw64/include/glib-2.0/glib/ghash.h:99:13: note: expected 'GHFunc {aka void (*)(void *, void *, void *)}' but argument is of type 'void (*)(const void *, const void *, void *)'
 void        g_hash_table_foreach           (GHashTable     *hash_table,
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

The important bit is this one (I have aligned it for better comparison):

```
expected    'GHFunc {aka void (*)(      void *,       void *, void *)}'
but argument is of type 'void (*)(const void *, const void *, void *)'
```

So it is a classic const correctnes warning.

The lambda has two const arguments, but the function pointer type (GHFunc) of `g_hash_table_foreach` is declared with more permissive non-const pointers.

That should not be a problem, so you can safely ignore it.